# Where does the id field, eg "wound-transition" in a jupyter notebook come from and what does it mean?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

If you look at the raw JSON of a jupyter notebook (python in this case), each cell has a field labeled "id", and they seem to be made up of hyphenated random word pairs, and are often rather funny.  A couple random examples:

```
 "id": "rough-girlfriend",
 "id": "wound-transition"
 "id": "orange-biography"
 "id": "mediterranean-viking",
```

I've done some googling but I can't seem to find any information on these fields! What do they mean? Where do they come from? How are they generated?

Any info much appreciated.

Comment: In a professional environment, those generated names can become nsfw. The implementation is childish at best and is a rather poor implementation. A better approach would be a Dewey decimal system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essentially, it seems they are meant to provide human-readable cell identifiers. There is a longer explanation of the need for such fields in the [enhancement proposal](https://jupyter.org/enhancement-proposals/62-cell-id/cell-id.html). The document also points [to the exact implementation in `nbformat`.](https://github.com/jupyter/nbformat/pull/189)

They are quite funny, as they are made of a random noun and a random adjective. I personally find them rather annoying though, as they tend to change unexpectedly, making git diffs ugly.

Comment: "making git diffs ugly." Do you know how to fix or disable them? I find them most annoying if you want to merge two notebook versions. Then you have to solve a merge conflict for every single cell.

Comment: Thanks! I had since found the JEP but somehow hadn't been able to find the implementation. Agreed on both counts about funny and annoying for git Diffs (how I found them in the first place)

Comment: For now, I live with it, haven't looked for a way to fix or disable them. I normally add changes using `git add -p` to have more precise control over what I'm adding, so normally I just skip the patches in which only a cell id has changed.

Comment: [How to avoid Jupyter cell-ids from changing all the time and thereby spamming the VCS diffs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68037147/745903)