# How to avoid Jupyter cell-ids from changing all the time and thereby spamming the VCS diffs?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython

As discussed in [q/66678305](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66678305/where-does-the-id-field-eg-wound-transition-in-a-jupyter-notebook-come-from-a), newer Jupyter versions store in addition to the source code and output of cells an [ID](https://jupyter.org/enhancement-proposals/62-cell-id/cell-id.html) for the purpose of e.g. linking to a cell.

However, these IDs aren't stable but often change even when the cell's source code was not touched. As a result, if you have the `.ipynb` file under version control with e.g. git, the commits end up having lots of rather funny sounding “changed lines” that don't correspond to any actual change made in the commit. Like,

```
   {
    "cell_type": "code",
    "execution_count": null,
-   "id": "respected-breach",
+   "id": "incident-winning",
    "metadata": {},
    "outputs": [],
```

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: In a professional environment, those generated names can become nsfw. The implementation is childish at best and is a rather poor implementation. A better approach would be a Dewey decimal system.

Comment: @Chris _Dewey decimal?_ What does it have to do with library topics? — No, really, a standard hexadecimal identifier would arguably still be best. But that's an unrelated discussion, the real problem is that there are identifiers _at all_.

Comment: When you add a cell to the end of a cell, it's id is +1 from the tail id.  If you add a cell in between 2 cells, it's id is the average of the previous id and the next id, etc. This can be done in base 36 easily enough.

Answer (score 2):

### Answer for Git on Linux. Probably also works on MacOS, but not Windows.

It is good practice to not VCS the `.ipynb` files as saved by Jupyter, but instead a *filtered* version that does not contain all the volatile information. For this purpose, various *git hooks* are available; the one I'm using is based on https://github.com/toobaz/ipynb_output_filter/blob/master/ipynb_output_filter.py.

Strangely enough, it turns out this script can *not* be modified to remove the `"id"` field from cells. Namely, if you try to remove that field in the filtering loop, like with

```
        for field in ("prompt_number", "execution_number", "id"):
            if field in cell:
                del cell[field]
```

then the `write` function from `jupyter_nbformat` will just put an `id` back in. It is possible to merely *change* the id to something constant, but then Jupyter will complain about nonunique ids.

As a hack to circumvent this, I now use this filter with a simple `grep` to delete the ID:

```
#!/bin/bash
grep -v '^ *"id": "[a-z\-]*",$'
```

Store that in e.g. `~/bin/ipynb_output_filter.sh`, make it executable (`chmod +x ~/bin/ipynb_output_filter.sh`) and ensure you have the following `~/.gitattributes` file:

```
*.ipynb filter=dropoutput_ipynb
```

and in your git config (either global `~/.gitconfig` or project)

```
[core]
         attributesfile = ~/.gitattributes
[filter "dropoutput_ipynb"]
         clean = ~/bin/ipynb_output_filter.sh
         smudge = cat
```

If you want to use a standard python filter in addition to that, you can invoke it before the `grep` in `~/bin/ipynb_output_filter.sh`, like

```
#!/bin/bash
~/bin/ipynb_output_filter.py | grep -v '^ *"id": "[a-z\-]*",$'
```

Comment: My jupyter auto-generates alphanumeric ids, so a slight change works for me.
`grep -v '^ *"id": "[a-z0-9\-]*",$'`